# Pass A.class through Spring BeanFactory::getBean()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to call a spring @bean method with type literal arguments.

This is the bean method

```
@Bean("m")
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public Mother getMother(Class<String> name){
    return new Mother(name);
}
```

Now i want a `Mother` object by using `BeanFactory::getBean`

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);           
    Object m3 = context.getBean("m", String.class);
```

This creates exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>'
```

Now how can I tell spring that the String.class argument is for `getMother`

Comment: You are trying to return a [bean of type `String`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-). Don't you mean `ctx.getBean("m", Mother.getClass()`? Btw, what value would the parameter have in your example? How should Spring know _which_ string to provide?

Comment: Maybe try to use array as a second argument : new Object[]{String.class}

Comment: The way you call, it calls another method of the BeanFactory that accepts bean name and it's type,you need to specify the other method that accepts arguments.

Comment: `Class<String> name` doesn't make any sense. The only value this parameter can have is `String.class`

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is [`<T> T BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Class<T> expectedType)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-). You are expecting a bean of type `Mother`, yet you tell the bean factory that it should return a bean of type `String`. Your bean with qualifier "m" is not a string, but a Mother. Let's fix this:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);           
Mother m3 = context.getBean("m", Mother.class);
```

If your bean is requiring a constructor parameter, you have to use the more specific overload [`Object BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);           
Object m3 = context.getBean("m", new[]{String.class});
```

Note that it is very unclear why the bean would require an argument of type `Class<String>`. There is only a single value with that type and that is the class singleton `String.class`. All Mother instances will share the reference to this class singleton (and not have a "real" name).